# How to upload a local directory as a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git, I have a project that I did locally, and I want it on GitHub in a repository.

How can I achieve this, because GitHub only has 'Upload Files', not an upload folder kind of option?

Comment: I would suggest the git and GitHub documentation. And you can check https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Comment: When you create a new repo on the `Github` they also tell you all of the commands to upload the repo.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  The linked duplicate is not an exact duplicate and doesn't answer the question at all.  The "How do you create a new project/repository?" sounds promising, but it is only about creating a local repository.  There is nothing about how to push it to Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Git from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

Make a repository at GitHub. It will give you a list of commands you can run to upload the project into the GitHub repository:

```
cd "Your project directory"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin "your GitHub URL"
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on "upload files" and then drag & drop the folder. All the files in the folder should be added (it works me on Google Chrome).

[image]

**But is not the recommended way. The best way is to create a local Git repository, and then push it to GitHub (see Sebastian Berge's answer).**